# S3 static website only opens with /index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, terraform

I am creating and uploading an S3 static `Vue.JS` site using `Terraform`. If I use `Terraform` to upload the actual files to the bucket then opening the site with `/index.html` fails and gives me a download dialog. If I manually upload the files in the console I can view the site as intended by visiting `/`.

My terraform file is below, what am I missing?

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.aws_access_key
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_key
  version    = "~> 3.0"
  region     = var.region
}

# create a bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "aws_s3_bucket_portal" {
  bucket  = "my-silly-test"
  acl     = "public-read"

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "index.html"
  }
}

# create bucket policy
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "portal_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_portal.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_portal.arn}/*"
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}

variable "mime_types" {
  default = {
    htm   = "text/html"
    html  = "text/html"
    css   = "text/css"
    js    = "application/javascript"
    map   = "application/javascript"
    json  = "application/json"
    png   = "image/png"
    jpg   = "image/jpg"
    jpeg  = "image/jpg"
    gif   = "image/gif"
    svg   = "image/svg+xml"
  }
}

# upload root files to the bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "website_files" {
  for_each = fileset(var.upload_directory, "**/*.*")
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_portal.bucket
  key = replace(each.value, var.upload_directory, "")
  source = "${var.upload_directory}/${each.value}"
  etag = filemd5("${var.upload_directory}/${each.value}")
  # acl = "public-read"
  content_type = lookup(var.mime_types, split(".", each.value)[length(split(".", each.value))-1], "text/html")
}
```

Comment: Before solving your problem, you should change a much more pressing detail: Your bucket policy allows EVERYONE to do everything in your bucket, including writing, overwriting, and deleting objects, as well as changing object ACLs. Please, never ever allow “s3:*” to everyone! Just imagine someone replacing one of your JavaScript files with one including malicious code.

Comment: Are you sure that your `aws_s3_bucket_object` works? I run your code and I had to fix a lot of staff in `aws_s3_bucket_object`. But this could be because my test static website is different then yours.

Comment: @marcin - Yes, confident that it definitely uploads my files. However, not confident that it uploads them the same way as the console does. What did you have to fix?

Comment: https://github.com/aviboy2006/angular-upload-s3cf/blob/master/angular_upload_s3cf.py#L157 see done in python while uploading app files. Check in terraform how to get file type by passing file path.

Comment: File paths `"${var.upload_directory}${each.value}"` were incorrect in my tests. They should be `"${var.upload_directory}/${each.value}"`, `acl = "public-read"` is not needed as you have public bucket policy, `lookup` was missing a default value.

Comment: @marcin I have updated my posted code based on your advice, but I am seeing the same result. When I navigate to the bucket `Properties` tab, scroll to the bottom and click the website endpoint link, all I get is an option to download content; I do not get a new tab with my SPA page displayed. If I add `/index.html` to the URL, I do see the page, so I believe the upload is working to a degree.

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue. Just to double check, can you deploy and make your website manually using AWS S3 console in a new bucket? This may give you some new clues/ideas what could be wrong with the automated approach as you could compare different settings between the buckets and objects?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Matt W. for bringing this issue up and your follow up, which led me to a solution!

When uploading an index.html file to a bucket using Terraform in order to be used as part of a S3 static website, set the content_type argument to "text/html".

```
# Add object to bucket
resource "aws_s3_object" "object_index" {
  bucket       = aws_s3_bucket.bucket_tf.bucket
  key          = "index.html"
  source       = "bucket_objects/index.html"
  content_type = "text/html"

  etag = filemd5("bucket_objects/index.html")
}
```

Here is a list of different content types that you are able to define for S3 objects.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aspera-on-cloud?topic=SS5W4X/dita/content/aws_s3_content_types.htm

A Terraform template that creates a S3 bucket configured to host a static website. A bucket policy is added which is required for the static website to be accessible to the public. An index.html file is uploaded to the bucket as an object to act as the home page of the static website.
https://github.com/thompsizzle/cloud-infrastructures/tree/main/AWS/S3_hello_world

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out this is simply how S3 is. When uploading to S3 the mime types need setting and the best way is to use the command line upload, not terraform.

However...

If you are using terraform to upload the files, make sure you set the mime types. Then the problem goes away if you use CloudFront to host the site because it will be deciding what to return to your client. The types still need to be there.